# How does a 2x2 deconv kernel with stride=2 work?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe, pytorch

For example, if the feature map is 8x8, than I use such a deconv and the feature map becomes 16x16, I'm confused that what the difference between:

```
deconv(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding='valid')
```

and

```
deconv(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding='same')
```

Since they will both make feature map 2 times larger, how do they work respectively?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find the explanations and interactive demo on [this web page](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/) very helpful.

Specifically, setting `stride=2` will double your output shape regardless of kernel size.
`kernel_size` determine how many output pixels are affected by each input pixel.
Setting `stride=2` and `kernel_size=2` simply "duplicates" your kernel on the output. Consider this 1D example. Suppose your kernel is `[a, b]` and your input is `[A, B, ...]`, then the output is

```
[A*a, A*b, B*a, B*b, ...]
```

For `kernel_size=3`, the output becomes

```
[A*a, A*b, A*c+B*a, B*b, B*c+C*a, ...]
```